# Between Runtime and compile time jdk version , which one can be greater

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

Which one of the two, runtime version and compile time version of a java program or a jar, should be greater or equal to the other?
Edit : Also what should be the version of JRE System Library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- So, my understanding is that you are compiling a java application with jdk1.6 and running the same application on a a runtime which is based on jdk1.8. (for example, it could jdk1.7 too here)
- Generally, JDK/JRE would be designed in such a way that it is backwards-compatible.
- It would be better to use a runtime environment version (JVM) that is greater than or equal to the compile version and not vice-versa.
- JDK(Compile-Version) <= JDK(Runtime-Version) - Correct
- JDK (Compile-Version) >= JDK(Runtime -Version) - Incorrect

Answer (score 3):

1. Java is backward compatible, most of the time you'll be able to run code compiled with the older jdk on a newer runtime.
2. When developing with the newer jdk you can specify what target vm versions you want to support.

So both scenarios are quite possible: code compiled with older jdk running on newer runtime, and code compiled with newer jdk running on old runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it made things pretty clear? One more thing, Can I set the target vm version of the jar?

Comment: Yes, you can compile your jar to run under specific (and later) version of java. Search for -target option here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: I went through your link and certain others. It concludes that one can set the target version but it has to be greater than the source version. So I don't think reverse is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally always be running a Java program using a runtime environment which is the *same* or *newer* than what was used to build it.  This is because Java generally ensures backwards compatibility to some extent.  However, forwards compatibility is not guaranteed.

For example, if you built a Java program using version 1.7, it would be expected to run in a 1.8 JRE.  But the reverse is not true, namely that a 1.8 program might not run correctly in an older 1.7 JRE.

Comment: Versions being equal would have any issues or the runtime version  should always be greater?

Comment: I think versions being equal is the ideal situation.  But if they are not equal, then make certain that you are running on a later and not earlier JRE.